# Android Studio trouble setting up Jackson Parser on gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, jackson, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having trouble adding the Jackson Parser dependency to my project.

Currently I'm using these lines of code on my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
```

The only Class I need is the ObjectMapper that I know it is in databind package. When I added these lines in the gradle I pressed the sync and everything did correctly.

The problem was running the project on the emulator, this error showed up in Messages in Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> >     copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE     File1:
> >     C:\Users\Igor.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.7.2\84ffa765dd258dbab8695963c41308b054f3a1cb\jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar
> >       File2:
> >     C:\Users\Igor.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.7.2\8b8310381b690e317f5f0574e9b2dd7034778b4c\jackson-core-2.7.2.jar

I tried to left only the databind library but I got no lucky with that. Same error.

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
```

I tried `Build -> Clean Project` and deleting the .gradle/cache but no luck either.

I have no clue what this could be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is the Maven Link to Jackson Repositories:

[link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) `Jackson`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To resolve the problem entirely I added all of these:

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
android {
...
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // It is not include NOTICE file
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // It is not include LICENSE file
}
...
}
```

in your `build.gradle` .

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.7.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3'
```

try this..

ref :-

> https://mobikul.com/how-to-use-jackson-parser/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).